# Quartz job retrigerring after server shutdown

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

Recently I've started to work with Quartz Persistent Job Store with the following properties:

```
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
```

I've defined a sample job with cron based trigger in spring:

```
 <bean id="sampleCronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
   <property name="jobDetail" ref="sampleJobDetail"/>
   <property name="cronExpression" value="0/5 * * * * ?"/>
```

I see that jobs is really gets executed each 5 seconds, all good.
Now I stop the program, which is a simple console application, no web containers or whatsoever, wait for ~ 30 seconds and rerun my program.
What I see is that the job gets triggered a lot of times when the scheduler starts.
For example, if the job is implemented as follows:

```
public class SampleJob implements Serializable, Job {
@Override
public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
    System.out.println("Executing the job Job  " + new Date());
}
```

}

The output right after the restart is like this:

```
 Executing the job Job  Mon Mar 31 08:34:18 IDT 2014
 Executing the job Job  Mon Mar 31 08:34:18 IDT 2014
 Executing the job Job  Mon Mar 31 08:34:18 IDT 2014
```

And then it works again every 5 seconds.

```
 Executing the job Job  Mon Mar 31 08:34:20 IDT 2014
 Executing the job Job  Mon Mar 31 08:34:25 IDT 2014
```

....

In real application I'm going to implement the job that will clean up the database (of course it won't run every 5 seconds :)) But I do plan that sometimes the server will be restarted and will stay down for some time, and I would like that this job will execute only once after the restart. Is it possible to do so?

I'm using SchedulerFactoyBean with the following configurations:

```
<bean id="quartzSchedulerFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean" destroy-method="destroy">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:scheduler-quartz.properties"/>
    <property name="quartzProperties" ref="qrtzProperties"/>
    <property name="autoStartup" value="true" />

    <property name="triggers">
        <list>             
            <ref bean="sampleCronTrigger"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean?

Comment: when scheduling the quarts it will trigger the event even before the application starts completely. But usually this wont be noticed but here your application is triggered at 5 sec interval so you are noticing it. !! that's all i believe

Comment: let me make it clear if the server takes20 sec to start it will run almost like 3 times. Because the within the first 5 sec the quarts is active.

Comment: Looks like Quartz executes the job for the time which it was unable to execute it because the app was not running. Try to add `System.out.println("Job is expected to be executed at " + context.getScheduledFireTime());` to your job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also try setting the following property

```
<property name="overwriteExistingJobs" value="true"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, geoand! This has resolved the issue (at least at the level of POC)!

Answer (score 5):

Try to set misfire instruction on sampleCronTrigger:

```
   <property name="misfireInstructionName" value="MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_DO_NOTHING"/>
```

Here is a big article about [misfire instructions](http://java.dzone.com/articles/quartz-scheduler-misfire)

Comment: It looks like it didn't solve the issue. But thanks anyway for pointing me on this direction, I'll keep digging here. +10 points for sure from me here :)